# Getting a date stamp to add in after i copy a range of data from one sheet to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on creating a makeshift database for a small project and currently i have the data moving from one sheet to another easily. However I am trying to add a time stamp and name next to the range i pasted so i can use them as identifiers. Below is the script I am using an it is creating quite a few issues. Once i add in the second "getRange" call it throws everything off. I want the data to be inserted in the first and second column corresponding with the data pasted.

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  var range=e.range;
  Logger.log(range);
  
  if (range.getSheet().getName() == "HAI Tracking Tool" && 
      range.getValue() == "FINISHED") {
    
     
        
        
        CopyRange();
  }
}   

function CopyRange() {
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HAI Tracking Tool'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('A7:K24'); 
 var data = range.getValues();
  
  
 var ts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Push Sheet'); 
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 3,18,11).setValues(data);
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,18,1,).setValue(new Date());
 ss.getRange('D7:K24').clearContent();
 ss.getRange('N2').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example sheet and an example of the input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

You want to add `date` and `name` values after the data that is being copied from the main sheet. I would suggest the following two modifications:

1. Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to append the current date and a name value to the existing data object:

   `var data = range.getValues().map(r=>[...r,new Date(),"name"]);`
2. Make the arguments of the `getRange` function dynamic so it accepts the dimensions of the `data` object:

   `ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);`

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range=e.range; 
  if (range.getSheet().getName() == "HAI Tracking Tool" && 
      range.getValue() == "FINISHED") {        
        CopyRange();
  }
}   

function CopyRange() {
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HAI Tracking Tool'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('A7:K24'); 
 var data = range.getValues().map(r=>[...r,new Date(),"name"]); // change "name" to anything else

 var ts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Push Sheet'); 
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
 ss.getRange('D7:K24').clearContent();
 ss.getRange('N2').clearContent();
}
```